# m3u8 extension video file is not working with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using AVPlayer to play a video from server, the video has m3u8 extension , but the video is not loading, others extensions are working perfectly.

Comment: did you face this error in conole : App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file

Comment: no, i have done the app Transport security settings in info.plist

Comment: did you try this : if let url = URL(string: "http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/102w0bsn0ge83qfv7za/102/hls_vod_mvp.m3u8"){

            let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            let controller=AVPlayerViewController()
            controller.player=player
            controller.view.frame = self.view.frame
            self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
            self.addChildViewController(controller)
            player.play()
        }

Comment: As far as I know, m3u8 is not a video file, but an audio playlist file. It's a text file. `AVAudioPlayer` is more suitable for it.

Comment: @MaxPevsner m3u8 can be for a video. I use them for HLS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U#M3U8